# iTerm2: Get the tab number from bash shell

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, shell, iterm2

For the day to day work, I login to a remote machine from my Mac through VNC. The font rendering in VNC viewer, and the resolution etc are horrible when seen on the retina display. So I use iTerm2 + ssh + screen. I have multiple screen sessions named like Terminal_1, Terminal_2 etc in the server. I have a script in server which would print the exact session name (PID.Terminal_*) for a requested session, or create a session if the requested on doesn't exit. I have a bash function in local Mac, which would ssh to the server, run the script, get the screen session and "screen -x " to it (-x because I sometimes share the session with others).

With all these setups, reconnecting to my screen sessions are now really simple as I just need to type "r 1", "r 2" etc after reopening iTerm2 or after reconnecting to network. So I open multiple tabs in iTerm2 and run r 1 in first, r 2 in second and so on.

I was wondering if there is a way to get the tab number from shell with the iTerm2 - Shell integration, so that all I would need to type is r in each tab (r is an alias for the bash function I have added), or may be even less with precmd.

Update: In the environment variable `ITERM_SESSION_ID=w0t2p0:xxxxx-xxxxx-xx`, w and t seems to be for Window and Tab. The first has w0t0p0, second has w0t1p0 and so on.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work. `echo ${ITERM_SESSION_ID:3:1}`. Please someone suggest if there is a better way of getting this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use with with tabs numbered under 10 and over 10 you'll need something a bit flexible.

`ITERM_SESSION_ID` contains something like `w0t0p0:01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-4567890ABCDE` which is a window number, a tab number, a pane number and a GUID. Importantly if you have say, 15 tabs in your only window with no panes you'll have the following prefixes: `w0t0p0`, `w0t1p0`, `w0t2p0`, `w0t3p0`, `w0t4p0`, `w0t5p0`, `w0t6p0`, `w0t7p0`, `w0t8p0`, `w0t9p0`, `w0t10p0`, `w0t11p0`, `w0t12p0`, `w0t13p0`, `w0t14p0`.

You could echo the different parts with this:

```bsh
if [[ $ITERM_SESSION_ID =~ w([0-9]+)t([0-9]+)p([0-9]+):* ]];
then
  echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
fi
```

Or set them to variables with:

```bsh
[[ $ITERM_SESSION_ID =~ w([0-9]+)t([0-9]+)p([0-9]+):* ]] \
&& W="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" T="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" P="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
```